# Why can't I query more than 1000 results for JIRA?

Tags: exec, logstash, jira, jira-plugin

I'm using the Logstash Input Plugin exec to run a command periodically to get JIRA data. Even if I set maxResults=99999, only 1000 results are returned. Here is my code right now:

```
input {
    exec {
        command => "curl -u username:password https://mycompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/latest/search?project=project&maxResults=8500"
        interval => 300
        type => "issues"
    }


} output {  
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "localhost:9200"
        index => "jira"
    }
}
```

I found online that if you run around 10 execs, and you set startAt to 0, 1000, 2000, etc, you get around 10000 responses. Is this faster than just one exec that pulls 8000 requests? How do I return more than 1000 responses with 1 exec?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@alpert's answer is correct, but I'll add a bit more detail.

JIRA's REST API (and most rest api's in general) support pagination to prevent that clients of the API can put too much load on the application. This means you cannot just pull in all issue data with 1 REST call.

You can only retrieve "pages" of max 1000 issues using the paging query parameters *startAt* and *maxResults*. See the *Pagination* section [here](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/).

If you run a JIRA standalone server then you can tweak the maximum number of results that JIRA returns, but for a cloud instance this is not possible. See this [KB article](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/changing-maxresults-parameter-for-jira-rest-api-779160706.html) for more info.

Your logstash configuration shows that you're periodically dumping all JIRA issues of a project into ElasticSearch. There are probably better ways to achieve what you're trying to do, than to use the JIRA GET /issue REST API call. So what do you use that data in ElasticSearch for?

Possibly there is a way to do what you need within JIRA, or you could look for a more convenient way to export all JIRA data, e.g. by using the [export functionality](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiracloud/exporting-issues-776636787.html).

Answer (score 1):

Taken from :https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/changing-maxresults-parameter-for-jira-rest-api-779160706.html

```
Unfortunately it is not possible to change this value as it falls under customizations which are not allowed in Atlassian Cloud.
```

It seems the best way is to use `startAt` aproach.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$username="JIRA Email";
$password="JIRA Password";        
$handle = curl_init();
$project_url="https://jirasite.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/search?jql=project='project id'&maxResults=100";
$project_url=trim($project_url);
 curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
 curl_setopt_array($handle, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $project_url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("content-type:application/json"),
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_BASIC,
    CURLOPT_USERPWD => $username . ':' . $password
      ));
     $response   = curl_exec($handle);
     print_r($response);
```

?>
Response Wille be 
{"expand":"schema,names","startAt":0,"maxResults":100,"total":52,"issues":[{"expand":............